# Get string between two strings [PHP]

Tags: php, preg-match

Okay this is probably all over the internet but I can't find a solution and been searching and trying different ways.

So the main way i've tried so far is as following:

string:

```
<div data-image-id="344231" style="height: 399.333px; background-image: url("/website/view_image/344231/medium"); background-size: contain;"></div>
```

code:

```
preg_match_all('/(style)=("[^"]*")/i', $value, $match);
preg_match('/background-image: url("(.*?)");/', $match[2][0], $match);
print_r($match);
```

I'm guessing I can't use:

`background-image: url("` and `");` instead the `preg_match`

Could someone give me some guidence on how I can achieve getting:

`"/website/view_image/344231/medium"`

Comment: I think you need to escape the first bracket after url `url\(` and the second closing brace `\)`

Comment: @Dale Please check updated question - How do i find it between the same strings with `"` added to the strings?

Comment: @mega6382 - If it's a minor issue please try and solve the question - thank you.

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6998123)

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Try using the single quotes for background image url. And use this regex to capture it `background-image: url\('(.*?)'\);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use single quotes for the background image url instead of double quotes you could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and get the style attribute from the div.

Then use `explode("; ")` which will return an array where one item of that array will be "background-image: url('/website/view_image/344231/medium')".

Loop through the array and use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a regex like for example `background-image: url\(([^)]+)\)` which will capture in a group what is between the parenthesis.

If there is a regex match, store the value from the group.

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div data-image-id="344231" style="height: 399.333px; background-image: url('/website/view_image/344231/medium'); background-size: contain;"></div>
HTML;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$elm = $doc->getElementsByTagName("div");
$result = array ();
$style = $doc->getElementsByTagName("div")->item(0)->getAttribute("style");
foreach (explode("; ", $style) as $str)
    if (preg_match ('/background-image: url\(([^)]+)\)/', $str, $matches)) {
        $result[] = $matches[1];
    }
echo $result[0];
```

That will give you:

> '/website/view_image/344231/medium'

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/RgKi0)